# What is my app url?

Tags: newmips

I created a newmips app yesterday and published (`deploy`) it. Now, I want to use it but I do not remember the **url** ?

The app name is `myApp` in the project `myProj` !

Note: I can still go to the studio, by login into newMips main page or directly to [https://alaind.newmips.studio]. So I can deploy again, and Mipsy will tell me the url of the deployment, but this info is surely already somewhere in the studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your environment is `myname` and your app is `myApp`

Then your application is accessible on: `https://myname-myapp.newmips.cloud/`

Comment: It would be nice to have it written on the page. How do I submit a feature request?

Comment: You can post it directly on https://www.github.com/newmipsOrg Thank you.

Comment: I did! No news.