# Web navigation to an entity

Tags: newmips

I have an newMips application deployed which I can access with `myname-myapp.newmips.cloud/` as explained on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855653/what-is-my-app-url).

Is there a url to open directly on an entity ? I am thinking of typing https://myname-myapp.newmips.cloud/employee and having the list of employees displayed in the browser (after authentication if I am not yet).

If we go one step further, https://myname-myapp.newmips.cloud/employee?id=employeeId would display this employee data sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity show page :

`https://myname-myapp.newmips.cloud/employee/show?id=employeeId`

Entity list page :

`https://myname-myapp.newmips.cloud/employee/list`

You only need to add /show to the url to be on an entity record, /list to list records

Comment: Perfect. Every thing is out-of-the-box. ... Except for the documentation..